# SyncML server to sync contacts to dumb phones

Tags: synchronization, phone

Would like to set up a server that can sync contacts on dumb phones. There's a commercial service like http://mycontacts-app.com/supported-phones (on the list see supported dumb phones), but I am interested in an self-hosted version, open source would be good.
I don't know how the syncing is technically done, maybe it's accomplished by Server Alerted Notifications (sending binary short messages).